# My most important pages does not get indexed, google search console

Tags: google-search-console, googlebot

I have a website with blog articles. I added it's sitemap to google search console and it say that the sitemap has been processed. However, half of my articles (the important pages) have not been indexed. I am not sure why some of them are indexed and some not?

They are all built from the same php-file using url slugs. They are also all linked from the index page so it is not as if they can not be found. They are all in my sitemap.xml file that Google Search console says it has processed. They are counted for in "pages submitted by me" section in the search console. They do not come up when I do a search for site: mysite.com (50% of my articles do, not all). They are not blocked in a robots.txt file or .htaccess file. They have been online several days before Google search console said it had processed my sitemap. There are no bad content, just simple articles about whitelisted subjects. There are no crawl errors or error response codes. This is why I ask this question because I have read all the other posts about this subject and I do not deem it a duplicate unless you can point out something I missed.

There might be one thing I did get wrong: I submitted my sitemap.xml, it said "pending" then some time later it said "processed". Does this not mean that google updated my site and added the pages in the sitemap to it's index? Is it just processed and waiting to crawl or something like that?

Can anyone please give some insight into this because I am at a total loss what to do. Only thing I got so far is to maybe split the sitemap into two files: one with site structure (categories/tags etc) and one with only articles, would this be a good option?

Comment: So I have clarified why I made this post, sorry, but the help desk answer is not enough this time. Either it is something in those "duplicate" answers I do not get or I have a different problem